# replace case insensitive values in XML, given case insensitive search values

Tags: xslt-2.0

I face the following issue:
i have the source XML file:

```
<TABLE NAME="TEST">
    <DATA RECORDS="78">
    <catalog>
       <book id="bk109">
          <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk110">
          <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk111">
          <description>An anthology of HORROR stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk112">
          <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk113">
          <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk114">
          <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep PROGRAMMER's reference.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk115">
          <description>An anthology of HORROR stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk116">
          <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects. Beware, this must not be matched.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk114">
          <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep PROGRAMMER's reference. Beware, this must not be matched.</description>
       </book>
       </catalog>
    </DATA>
    </TABLE>
```

Given the following xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs functx">

    <xsl:param name="search-text" as="xs:string">An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.
Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep programmer's reference.</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="replacement-text" as="xs:string">Value we need to store in the (description) element.
Another value we need to store in the (description) element.</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="search-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize($search-text, '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:param name="search-terms-is" as="xs:string*" select="for $term in $search-terms return concat('^', lower-case(functx:escape-for-regex($term)), '$')"/>

    <xsl:param name="replace-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize($replacement-text, '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:include href="http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="description[some $search-term in $search-terms-is satisfies matches(., $search-term, 'i')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="matched-term" as="xs:string" select="$search-terms-is[matches(current(), ., 'i')]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="replacement" as="xs:string" select="$replace-terms[index-of($search-terms-is, $matched-term)]"/>
        <xsl:value-of
            select="$replacement"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

result is ok:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TABLE NAME="TEST">
<DATA RECORDS="78">
<catalog>
   <book id="bk109">
      <description>Value we need to store in the (description) element.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <description>Another value we need to store in the (description) element.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <description>Value we need to store in the (description) element.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <description>Value we need to store in the (description) element.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk113">
      <description>Value we need to store in the (description) element.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk114">
      <description>Another value we need to store in the (description) element.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk115">
      <description>Value we need to store in the (description) element.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk116">
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects. Beware, this must not be matched.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk114">
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep PROGRAMMER's reference. Beware, this must not be matched.</description>
   </book>
   </catalog>
</DATA>
</TABLE>
```

but if in the search terms, i have twice the same terms, in different case, i get error

xsl:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs functx">

    <xsl:param name="search-text" as="xs:string">An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.
An anthology of HORROR stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="replacement-text" as="xs:string">Value we need to store in the (description) element.
Another value we need to store in the (description) element.</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="search-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize($search-text, '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:param name="search-terms-is" as="xs:string*" select="for $term in $search-terms return concat('^', lower-case(functx:escape-for-regex($term)), '$')"/>

    <xsl:param name="replace-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize($replacement-text, '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:include href="http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="description[some $search-term in $search-terms-is satisfies matches(., $search-term, 'i')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="matched-term" as="xs:string" select="$search-terms-is[matches(current(), ., 'i')]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="replacement" as="xs:string" select="$replace-terms[index-of($search-terms-is, $matched-term)]"/>
        <xsl:value-of
            select="$replacement"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TABLE NAME="TEST">
<DATA RECORDS="78">
<catalog>
   <book id="bk109">
      Error on line 30 
  XTTE0570: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value of variable
  $matched-term ("^an anthology of horror storie...", "^an anthology of horror storie...") 
  at xsl:apply-templates (#23)
     processing /TABLE/DATA[1]/catalog[1]/book[1]/description[1]
  at xsl:apply-templates (#23)
     processing /TABLE/DATA[1]/catalog[1]/book[1]
  at xsl:apply-templates (#23)
     processing /TABLE/DATA[1]/catalog[1]
  at xsl:apply-templates (#23)
     processing /TABLE/DATA[1]
  in built-in template rule
```

how could i alter stylesheet, so as not to have this error occur?
The example was uploaded online by Martin Honnen, who kindly answered my previous question.
online at http://xsltransform.net/gVhD8RA

Comment: Well, you haven't explained which element you want to use for the match and replacement if there are several, assuming the first match suffices you can change `<xsl:variable name="matched-term" as="xs:string" select="$search-terms-is[matches(current(), ., 'i')]"/>` to `<xsl:variable name="matched-term" as="xs:string" select="$search-terms-is[matches(current(), ., 'i')][1]"/>`.

Comment: i am afraid there may be more than one occurrences, so the above solution will be for the above example. I will try and see what i can do with the above, thank you